# Проверка двух строк одновременно

Tags: c#

```
 for (int i = 2; i < list.Count; i += 3)
            {
                if ((int.Parse(list.ElementAt(i))==5 ))
                {
                    listBox.Items.Add(list.ElementAt(i - 2));
                    listBox.Items.Add(list.ElementAt(i - 1));
                    listBox.Items.Add(list.ElementAt(i));
                    listBox.Items.Add("\n");
                }
            }
```

Этот цикл выполняет условие "Третья строка = 5" и выводит записи удовлетворяющие это условие. С ним всё хорошо, но мне нужно добавить туда ещё условие "Вторая строка = 2". Как это можно сделать?

Comment: какого типа `list`? `List<string>`?

Comment: @aepot  List<string>

Comment: Я исправил ошибку в ответе.

Comment: Имхо, в данном конкретном случае вовсе незачем парсить строку в `int`. Пишите просто `if (list[i] == "5"` и т. п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень странно вы используете `Enumerable.ElementAt(i)`, когда `List<T>` имеет индексатор, можно просто `list[i]`. И при определенном количестве элементов спика, вы можете получить `IndexOutOfRangeException`, для защиты от этого `list.Count` я поменял на `list.Count - 2`. А индексацию лучше начинать с нуля.

```csharp
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 2; i += 3)
{
    if (int.Parse(list[i + 2]) == 5 && int.Parse(list[i + 1]) == 2)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(list[i]);
        listBox.Items.Add(list[i + 1]);
        listBox.Items.Add(list[i + 2]);
        listBox.Items.Add("\n");
    }
}
```